# Fixing sticky keyboard keys

Tags: keyboard

Been having problems with a 5 year old keyboard.

The problem here is that the keys are rather hard to press, sticky, and unresponsive.  I already did a full keyboard cleaning where I pried off each key and cleaned each key from top to bottom and removed all the gunk and grime that were in and between these keys on the keyboard side.

Only problem is, although this helped my sticky key problem a little bit, I'm noticing that more and more of my keys are just less responsive.  They take more force to "push down" so that the computer recognizes I hit a key.  Sometimes after I hit a key, it'll be really slow at coming back up, which makes it frustrating for me since I type 80-90 WPM.

After prying the keys off, I noticed the silicon nipple/nubbin that is in each key seems to be very soft to the touch and not very springy.  This makes me think that silicone "layer" that's on the bottom side of the keyboard is just worn out from too many button presses.  I've had this happen before with game controller buttons, where the buttons stop losing their responsiveness due to overuse.  Had to take apart these controllers and wap buttons around so that the buttons I used the most on my gamepad got the "good" little rubber/silicone pad.

Any way to put the spring back into these things or am I out of luck?

Comment: honestly? It sounds a lot like the silcone layer has degraded over time, and replacing the keyboard would be the least difficult solution. Unless there's something 'special' about this keyboard, chances are a basic cheap and cheerful keyboard would cost less than trying to fix it. I

Comment: I agree with Journeyman, get a new keyboard. I just bought an OK one at Wall-Mart for $11 so not worth fixing. You may want to do yourself a favor and get a better quality one this time if you use it a lot.

Comment: Seriously, unless there is something obnoxiously special about this keyboard (in which case that should have been noted to start) then stop wasting your time dealing with an FRU.  Replace and move on.  Even if there IS something special about this keyboard, unless a like replacement is gunna be exorbitant or you are just THAT broke, replace it and stop wasting your time here :)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Nah - I've grown fond of this keyboard.  It was a nicely affordable $30 keyboard I picked up way back when during a CompUSA (remember those guys?) sale.  It's a Logitech Media Elite Keyboard: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41AYMQB96ZL.jpg  It's nothing terribly special, but I liked the bigger control/shift/alt keys.  Anyway, I'll look into getting a new keyboard - thanks for the advice.

Comment: Nothing wrong with fixing things - just in this case, you pretty much need to turn back time (i have no idea if there's anything that would de-degrade rubber), or replace a specific component. I suppose if you had a few hours to spare, you could fabricate a replacement rubber panel somehow, or convert it to a mechanical ;p

Comment: You said that you cleaned the keys, but did you open the keyboard up to clean the internal layers? Dust, dirt, oil, grime, drinks, etc. don’t stay only *on* the keys, they can get **inside** the keyboard. If you spilled a drink or have a lot of dust or whatever, they can get between the layers and cause it to stick a bit which would also give the “less-springy” feel.

Comment: For future reference, that point-of-depression at which the computer registers an input from your keyboard is called the "actuation point".  Here's an informative [guide](https://www.mechanical-keyboard.org/switch-types/) on keyboard switch mechanics, it's based on mechanical keyboards but it adequately explains the general structure and vernacular associated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just get a new keyboard, thanks to @Journeyman_Geek's advice.  Guess my keyboard's just hitting its age from getting used every day since I bought it 5+ years ago.  Oh well.